# toggle divs so only one is open at a time, but be able to close them all as well javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these divs that I can toggle onclick to scale larger one at a time.  It works perfectly except that once one is enlarged, one is always enlarged.  I am using toggleOpen for this.  I am looking to be able to make it so that it can do what it already does, but then onclick of the enlarged div have it go back to its original size without having to toggle with another div.  In other words, I need a way to make the page go back to a state where all the divs are in original size.  I have tried else statements to no avail as well as adding another function to remove class.  I only want a js solution - no jquery or anything else please.  Here is the JS portion of it.

```
const event = document.querySelectorAll('.eventsBorder')

function toggleOpen() {
    let opened = document.getElementsByClassName('large')[0];
    if(opened!=undefined)
        opened.classList.toggle('large');
    this.classList.toggle('large');
} 

event.forEach(eventsBorder => eventsBorder.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
```

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Angel074/pen/bGVLRMP)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: To be clear, do you want the dive to return to normal size after a period of time or on a subsequent click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `opened` variable gives you back a list of all the HTML elements which have the `large` class, and when you click again on an already enlarged `div` that automatically satisfied this criteria. So, what happens is that if you click on the same item twice, your `toggleOpen` function first removes the `large` class from that item and then adds it again because of the following line in your code-

```
this.classList.toggle('large');
```

The best way to achieve what you want would be to make sure that in addition to `opened` not being `undefined`, you should also make sure `opened` is not the same item as the one you clicked on. You can accomplish that using-

```
if(opened != undefined && opened != this)
```

Here is a link to the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/schikara/pen/qBOxpOy) to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are using querySelectorAll to select all elements with the class "large", then you're toggling the class. If you toggle the class, it will no longer be a part of that query selection, as it no longer has that class applied, so it will not be able to remove it.

```
const event = document.querySelectorAll('.eventsBorder')

event.forEach(eventsBorder => 
              eventsBorder.onclick = () => 
              eventsBorder.classList.toggle('large'));
```

This seems to accomplish what you'd like.